# How to run docker image in private registry

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a private insecure registry on an Ubuntu Server 18.04 (using docker-compose), whose IP is let's say 192.168.168.168; when on a Windows client I browse from Chrome to

http://192.168.168.168:5000/v2/_catalog

I get

```
{"repositories":["hello-world2","mywebservice"]}
```

which is ok, since I pushed them to the private registry.
So:

1. How do I run those images on the Ubuntu server?
2. With regard to the "mywebservice", which is a REST webservice, how do I run it, so I can access it from a browser of my local Windows client?

I already tried

```
docker run 192.168.168.168:5000/mywebservice
```

but got

> Unable to find image '192.168.168.168:5000/mywebservice:latest'
>   locally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Docker registry is not a Docker Engine and it cannot run containers.

If one wants to run a Docker container on the same server where the Docker registry is, it is necessary to pull the image from the registry to a Docker client (using `docker pull localhost:5000/image_name`), and then run it the usual way.